# Using wait_for_connection on a newly created virtual machine in an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, virtual-machine, libvirt

So I'm creating a new virtual machine (Machine B) on a server (Machine A) through an ansible playbook and I need it to be booted up (have an IP address) before I proceed with the playbook.

I'm using the ansible `wait_for_connection` module to try to achieve that but it tests the connection of Machine A instead of Machine B.

How do I use the `wait_for_connection` module to wait for Machine B (or test its connection) given that I don't know the IP of Machine B?

Machine B is a windows VM and I'm using libvirt to create the VM.